# How to add an img tag with attribute values via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to know how to create an image tag with a class of "field" through javascript or jquery. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to create an image tag without any class? Did you read any documentation at all? E.g. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var img = '<img src="my.jpg" class="field" />';    
$('body').append(img);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.className = 'field';
//set any other properties you want
//add it to the dom
```

Or using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

```
var $img = $('img', {
    'class': 'field' //you can add more properties
});
//Add it to the dom
```

Comment: For class attributes, I would recommend using classList. Such as img.classList.add('myclass')

Comment: Thank you this just made my life easier!